# Row Height AutoFit doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

So, today is my bad day
I discovered that excel row AutoFit - doesn't work

```
a = "Please"
b = "Do AutoFit"
range01.Value = a & vbNewLine & b  
range01.EntireRow.AutoFit // First and last line are horizontally cutted
```

Chr(10) instead of vbNewLine - doesn't help
It works only if I write without line breaks:

```
range01.value = a & b
range01.EntireRow.AutoFit  //  works !!!  Thanks to Microsoft !
```

Comment: Have you tried making a new height for the row, then setting autofit?

Comment: You need to make sure that the cells that have line breaks in them have "Wrap Text" turned on.  Check out this article for more info: http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-insert-a-line-break-in-a-cell/

Comment: Wrap Text is On. I will now try Jared's suggestion

Comment: @JaredFarrish, `rng01.RowHeight = 20 / rng01.EntireRow.AutoFit` - cell changes its height, but the first and the last line are allways "half visible"

Comment: Try setting it to taller than you need, like 50, then autofit. I'm not sure if this will work, but I know sometimes it will autofit shrink instead of grow larger. You might also add a programmatic wrap call like @joseph4tw suggested.

Comment: `WrapText = true` - works, even without changing RowHeight. Please, place your comments as Answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @joseph4tw - See the comment above. `:)`

Comment: Are you dealing with merged cells?  If so, AutoFit doesn't work with merged cells no matter what you do, unfortunately. @JaredFarrish Thanks :)

Comment: No, cell is not merged. Strange, but SomeHow, It's needed to write `WrapText = true` although the cell is wrapped in the sheet view. So, place your answer. It seems Solved

Comment: Alegro, to notify someone who has commented and you want to comment back, use the `@` plus username, like @joseph4tw. That way they get a little notification. Tip: Use `tab` after typing `@j` and you'll a list of matching commenters, then hit `enter` to select that username.

Comment: @ Jared, I allways try to type `@` and tab, but sometimes it works, sometimes - doesn't work, like just now. After pressing tab - there is no list of commenters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that the cells that have line breaks in them have "Wrap Text" turned on. You can turn it on with VBA like so:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "Please"
    b = "Do AutoFit"
    Range("A1").Value = a & vbNewLine & b
    Range("A1").WrapText = True
    Range("A1").EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Autofit doesn't work on merged cells. My guess is that's what you are trying to do.

Work around this by simulating the autofit on a single cell with the same width as your merged cell and set the height it gives you.

Something like this:

```
Dim YourString As String, a As String, b As String
Dim TempLoc as Range

a = "Please"
b = "Do AutoFit"
YourString = a & vbNewLine & b
Set TempLoc = range01.offset(0, 10) ' Given the column 10 columns to the right has the exact same witdh as your merged cell.

' Autofit a single cell to get correct height
With TempLoc
       .Value = YourString
       .WrapText = True
       .EntireRow.AutoFit
       .RowHeight = TempLoc.RowHeight
       .ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! Very useful to know that autofit doesn't work on merged cells. Merged cells are the devils invention.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: This simple one line works fine for my needs thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I solved an issue with this - I had a row with two merged cells both containing multi-line text with Chr(10) linefeeds - with Wrap set ON (but no lines actually wrap - only the Chr(10)s cause new lines). Autofit wouldn't work due to the merged cells.

The VBA workaround was to use a spare cell on the same row, and fill it with the same number of Chr(10) as found in one (either) of the multi-line cells. Then call AutoFit for that cell now containing the same number of invisible line feeds. **Make sure** the font and size are the same in the spare cell!

```
' make C36 spare cell contain the same number of Chr(10) as D36, using a Repeat function :
' (after counting Chr(10) by comparing the length before and after substituting Chr(10) with "")
Worksheets(1).Range("C36").Value = _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept(Chr(10), _
     Len(Worksheets(1).Range("D36").Value) - Len(Replace(Worksheets(1).Range("D36").Value, Chr(10), "")))
Worksheets(1).Range("C36").Rows.AutoFit
```

An alternative method for other scenarios could be to use an extra, hidden, worksheet - set a single cell to the same column width as your merged cells, copy the contents over, call autofit (which should work on the unmerged cell), then use the resulting rowheight from that one.

Comment: Brilliant solution with the linked cell on the same row!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to shrink the column width down a bit for the column(s) that are causing the autofit problem, select all the rows you want to change, autofit the row height by double-clicking one of the row separators, and finally autofit the column(s) from the first step by double-clicking the column separator(s).  Probably works best if only one or just a few columns consistently have the most text in their cells.